# Can't seem to get item to float:right until breaking div -- then allow to get cutoff

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/erfjW/2/

I am trying to get this jsfiddle to have the RHS not drop down to the next level when the browser window gets too small. Instead, I would like it to hold position -- as if it was inside of a fixed-width parent container. The content on the LHS should not move.

I tried working from the source of SO -- the navbar at the top does basically what I want, except the content is allowed to move away from the LHS. When I tried to tweak this I broke the entire functionality.

If this isn't possible in a simple manner I'm open to other suggestions. Thanks.

EDIT: The RHS area is a search box. I do not wish it to override URL links which are left-justified. As such, absolute positioning won't work here -- it will render above the URL links instead of allowing itself to be cut off once it hits them.

Comment: Is the simple solution of setting a `min-width` on `body` (or your container) an option?

Comment: ... Man. CSS is frustrating. Yeah. I think this will do it, give me a few minutes to play around with the rest of the website / make sure this 'feels' right.

Comment: This is trivial using tables, of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... as said above, one solution is to use absolute positioning. I made a fiddle for that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/erfjW/3/).

The issue you're running into is that you don't want either side's content to override the other - there's really no way to guarantee this. As you can see from the fiddle, *eventually*, with a small enough screen size, Content A will override Content B.

The way around that is to use a fixed width container, and define a width (in pixels or percentage) for the left and right divs. I made a fiddle for this solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vonkly/erfjW/4/).

Comment: Note: You *can* use `min-width` on your container, but keep in mind that IE doesn't support that property.

Comment: IE does support `min-width`. Well, IE6 doesn't, but there's a [simple fix](http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be `position: absolute; right: 0`.

Comment: Ah, sorry... I left a constraint off of the initial problem that is relevant. The text on the RHS should be aware of the LHS -- it can't go over/under it and should respect it's positioning.

Comment: Then what should happen when both don’t fit?

Comment: Oh, now I see. You want it to overflow to the right when it doesn’t fit.